# How do I lock sveltekit down to a version?

Tags: node.js, svelte, sveltekit

I’m using `svelte@next` How do I lock this down to a specific sveltekit version?

This is nodejs and package.json

`npm init svelte@next my-app`

This is package file:

```
"@sveltejs/kit": "next",
        "@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte": "next",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to specify the version just like this: `"@sveltejs/kit": "1.0.0-next.310"`

you can visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sveltejs/kit to see all versions available

Answer (score 0):

You will have to check the `create-svelte` repository to find the right version for your need. You can find them directly on npm at https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-svelte. For example the latest version is `2.0.0-next.127` so you could run `npm init svelte@2.0.0-next.112 my-app`.